# How to create two sections of the same screen using a custom view controller

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, ipad

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to create a custom view controller which will split the screen into two sections and manage the sections seperately in the same manner that the iPad Zillow app does this?
See http://www.zillow.com/ipad/ if you are unfamiliar with the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UISplitViewController`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure this is correct. In portrait mode the UISplitViewController replaces the "master" section with a popover. The Zillow application keeps this section fixed in place. Perhaps there is some property or override to accomplish this, but I was unable to find one.


http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH3-SW8

Comment: There is a private API, (`setHidesMasterViewInPortrait:`), but other than that you would need to create your own, which would be quite time consuming, and possibly a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a split view controller that works like the one in that app then you will have to write your own, `UISplitViewController` doesn't really have any settings that can be customized.